# My entity framework 6 class library works from one project but not from the other

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, dll

I have created a class library (targeted to .NET 4) containing all my entity framework models/context. I am referencing that class library from one project (targeted to .NET 4.5.1) and it works great, then I am referencing the same class library from another project (targeted to .NET 4) and it gives me this error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
Multiple types with the name 'places' exist in the EdmItemCollection in different namespaces.  Convention based mapping requires unique names without regard to namespace in the EdmItemCollection.
```

And then many more of the same error for all my entities.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be hitting a type conflict. When resolving types EF does not use namespaces and if it sees two types with the same names it sometimes does not know which one to use. You can find more details in the bug EF team is tracking this issue: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/483. Also note that as of EF6 most scenarios are fixed when using Code First - see this work item for more details: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/911

Comment: There is not even a similar type name in my solution.. It cannot be a conflict.. Any ideas? How can I resolve it with code first?